# Apps Script: Setfont italics for active row based on trigger cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typography

thanks in advance for any help.

I want to trigger italicizing the entire row if column 13 of the row contains "y" (ideally if there is a way to set font as normal if not containing "y" that would be grand too)

Here's what I tried (it's part of an onEdit nest). Currently it is only making the trigger column italics rather than the whole row as I am wanting.

```
function onEdit(e) 
  {
      //Formula to run
   {
    spreadsheetWizard(e);
    spreadsheetWizardII(e);
    spreadsheetWizardIII(e);
    moveRow(e);
    }
  }


function spreadsheetWizardIII()
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
    var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
    var editrow = range.getRow()
    var trigger = sheet.getRange(editrow,13)

    // Header Rows to ignore
    if(range.getRow() <= 1) return;

    // Sheet(s) to include / exclude
    if(sheet.getName() !== 'Masterlist') return;

    // Trigger Column
    if(range.getColumn() != 13) return;

    if(trigger.getValue() == "y") 
      {
      editrow.setFontStyle('italic');
      }
  }
```

Comment: In your question, do you want to modify `spreadsheetWizardIII`? If my understanding is correct, are the other 3 functions related to `spreadsheetWizardIII` and your question? And, in your script, the event object is not used. Do you want to achieve your goal without using the event object? And about `Currently it is only making the trigger column italics rather than the whole row as I am wanting.`, in your goal, you want to set `setFontStyle('italic')` to `var trigger = sheet.getRange(editrow,13)`? In that case, how about `trigger.setFontStyle('italic')`?

Comment: Hi Tanaike,

The other functions are not related to this question. I included them purely to show that this is part of an onEdit nest.

I don't actually know what difference it makes including or not including the event object - I am very much still learning!

And apologies for the confusion - what I want to achieve is an entire row itallicised if column 13 of that row contains "y"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your question, you say `Currently it is only making the trigger column italics rather than the whole row as I am wanting.`. In your reply, you say `what I want to achieve is an entire row itallicised if column 13 of that row contains "y"`. From them, I cannot still understand your expected situation. For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your actual question.